# Programa que calcula uma série de N termos

Tags: python-3.x

Escreva um programa para calcular o valor da série, para N termos.

S = 0 + 1/2! + 2/4! + 3/6! + ...

Comecei a fazer o programa como mostro no código abaixo, porém não estou conseguindo obter o resultado correto.

Por favor me ajudem! Grato!

```
def fatorial_for(numero):
    resultado = 1
    for k in range(1, numero + 1):
        resultado *= k
    return resultado

n = int(input('Digite um número inteiro positivo: '))
s = 0
for i in range(0, n + 1):
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        s = s + (i / fatorial_for(j * 2))
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste trecho:

```
for i in range(0, n + 1):
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        s = s + (i / fatorial_for(j * 2))
```

não tem sentido este segundo loop. Use:

```
for i in range(0, n + 1):
    s += i / fatorial_for(i * 2)
```

Comment: Nossa agora que fui ver que não precisa mesmo, muito obrigado!!